# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Establishing tcp connections on remote port 3306 has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, mysql, tcp, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 to implement api in **subdomain** for example: **api.domain.com**

I copied the laravel from local to sharing host. In **public_html/api** folder.

In local eveything works fine, but in server I got this error:

> **PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Establishing tcp connections on remote port 3306 has been disabled for security reasons.**

When I try to connect database by laravel 5.

What should I do?

Comment: Well use another port when creating PDO connection? Show the code you use to create the PDO connection..

Comment: Check your database configuration, and talk to your host.

Comment: @Naruto no i dont use another connection using PDO, as i mentioned my code works fine in local.

Comment: @AmirhosseinPooya Hi, please see that [post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Answer (score 15):

Use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` in your **.env file** for `DB_HOST` variable.